# Macro expansion and concatenation in cpp

Tags: c++, macros, trace, expansion

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define PRINT_INFO() printf("%s",__FUNCTION__)
#define PRINT(str,...) printf("%s %s", PRINT_INFO(), str, ##__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    PRINT_INFO(); // expected output = main
    PRINT("Hello %s", "World"); // expected output = main Hello World
    return 0;
}
```

Consider the above code snippet in c++. My intention is to use the PRINT_INFO() macro inside PRINT() macro in a way that will also print the parameters sent from main.

However, I am getting
>> Command terminated by signal 11

How can I get what I intend to get?

Comment: would you share the errors with us?

Comment: How are you invoking this macro?  [mre] please

Comment: Use proper C++, type-safe, templates instead of C varargs?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik how?

Comment: By using variadic templates, which have been supported since C++11.

Comment: @PaulSanders post updated, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what happens as the PRINT macro is expanded:

```
printf("%s %s", PRINT_INFO(), str, ##__VA_ARGS__)
-> printf("%s %s", printf("%s",__FUNCTION__), str, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

I don't think this is what you intended.

Perhaps you meant:

```
#define PRINT_INFO() printf("%s ",__FUNCTION__)
#define PRINT(str,...) do { PRINT_INFO(); printf(str, ##__VA_ARGS__); } while(0)
```

I don't see the value that having two macros adds. Another option would be:

```
#define PRINT(str,...) printf("%s:%d: "  str, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

This gives the line information as well, you can just remove that if you do not want it.

Comment: That's true, that it's not what I intended. My intention is to get output of the first macro appended with the second macros output. What is the proper way to do so?

Comment: With no '\n' or `fflush` the crash happens before you see the output of the first macro. It's buffered.

Comment: Even with '\n' the crash happens.

Comment: Yes, the crash will happen, but you will see the first message. Oh, I think I misread your comment. Will update answer.

Comment: Well, yes, because the first PRINT_INFO() prints "main " and the second PRINT() prints "main Hello World".

Comment: That is, according to your comments, what you expect.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the solution if printf does not return any value? Let's think about `TRACE()`.

Comment: That's a separate question. I was just answering why you were seeing the crash.

Comment: Thanks. Your last code snippet solution is exactly what I wanted. However, could you explain why str is not being considered respectively for first placeholder %s?

Comment: `str` is the user's format string. This needs to be concatenated with the format string of the information you want to inject. In this case, we need `"%s:%d: "` for the filename and line number plus the user's format string. In other language you might write something like `"%s:%d:" + str` but in C there is no string concatenation operator so `"%s:%d:" str` will do the trick. Note there is no comma there. This works because in C `"x" "y"` is equivalent to `"xy"`. Hope this makes it clearer.